# Cant get item to delete in firebase with react

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

My delete button, and create button wont work, I keep getting this error:

> uncaught error:reference.child failed: first argument was an invalid path

[image]

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, selectedId } from 'react-native';
    import firebase from './firebase';
    export default class App extends Component {
    carDatabase = firebase.database().ref('car');
     state = { cars: {}, selectedId: '' }
     // Read
     componentDidMount() {
       this.carDatabase.on('value', cars => {
         const carsJSON = cars.val();
         this.setState({ cars: carsJSON === null ? {} : carsJSON });
       })
       // this.carDatabase.push({color: 'yellow'})
     }
     // Create
     create() {
       this.carDatabase.push({color: 'yellow'})  
       this.setState({selectedId: ''})
     }
     // Update
     update() {
      this.carDatabase.child(this.state.selectedId).set({color: 'blue'}) 
      this.setState({selectedId: ''})
    }
     // Delete
     deleteCar() {
        if(this.state.selectedId === '') {
          return;

        }
       // firebase.database().ref('car/').remove
       this.carDatabase.child(this.state.selectedId).set(null)
      this.setState({selectedId: ''})
    }
        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                 <TextInput value={this.state.selectedId} style={styles.textInput}></TextInput>
                   <Button title="create" onPress={() => this.create()}></Button> 
                   <Button title="update" onPress={() => this.update()}></Button> 
                   <Button title="delete" onPress={() => this.deleteCar()}></Button> 
                   {
       Object.keys(this.state.cars).map( ( index) =>
       <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedId})}>
         <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.cars[index])}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     )
    }

           {/* <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.cars, null, 2)}</Text> */}
         </View>
            );
        }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     textInput: {
       backgroundColor: 'green',
       height: 30,
       width: '100%'
     },
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
     }
    });
```

Comment: I added a quick answer below. But in cases like this it is always very useful to also have the stack trace of the error, including your pointing out what lines the stack trace points to. If my answer doesn't help you solve the problem, add those to your question (and please always add them going forward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `this.state.selectedId` contains something that is not a valid path in your database. You can find out what that actually is by logging the value before you use it. For example:

```
deleteCar() {
  console.log(this.state.selectedId)
  this.carDatabase.child(this.state.selectedId).set(null)
  this.setState({selectedId: ''})
}
```

Most likely it seems that `this.state.selectedId` is null or empty. Right now you're only checking for an empty string, so you might have better results if you do this instead:

```
deleteCar() {
  if (this.state.selectedId && this.state.selectedId.length) {
    this.carDatabase.child(this.state.selectedId).set(null)
    this.setState({selectedId: ''})
  }
}
```

Comment: this is my firebase danni2-d27c3
car
-Lrq2jMUQd2unU9EuytE
-LrtAX54kd97kBmOLtA4

Comment: "isn't working" is not very actionable. If you add the `console.log` that I have in my first code snippet, what does it output? Also see the comment I left on your question, as it's hard to help without more complete information. I also highly recommend you check out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it contains many tips how to make it more likely that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys(this.state.cars).map( (carId, index) =>
  this.setState({ selectedId: carId})}>
   {`${carId}: ${JSON.stringify(this.state.cars[index])}`}